NVIDIA RTX 4060 Issue on Kubuntu: Black Screen After Installing Drivers
I'm using an Asus TUF laptop running Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q. While the system detects the GPU, installing any NVIDIA drivers (e.g., nvidia-driver-535) results in the laptop functioning until a reboot, where it then shows a black screen. I can only access the system via recovery mode or by uninstalling the NVIDIA drivers.
I’ve tried different kernels (6.8 and 5.15), configured PRIME settings to force the NVIDIA GPU, and attempted to rebuild kernel modules, but the issue persists. Additionally, nvidia-smi fails to communicate with the driver, and errors related to NVIDIA modules and ACPI are frequently logged.
I’d appreciate any advice to resolve this issue and enable my NVIDIA GPU to work properly without causing black screens after rebooting. Thank you!
Detailed Error Summary:
System and Configuration:
Laptop Model: Asus TUF

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q (AD107M) + Intel UHD Graphics (Raptor Lake-P).

OS: Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Active Kernel: Currently 6.8.0-49-generic (also tried 6.8.0-47-generic, 5.15.0-107-generic, and 5.15.0-125-generic).

NVIDIA Drivers Tried: nvidia-driver-535, 525, and others listed by ubuntu-drivers devices.


Your 4060 should use the latest Nvidia driver available, 555 or 560 depending if you're using the graphics-drivers PPA. Not sure why an older driver wouldn't work though.
